# Fix Epson XP-2100 Scanner connection

Tags: scanner, epson

PC and printer/scanner are connected via WiFi and I can print anything from my PC (*Ubuntu 20.04*).

But my Scan-Software insists in getting a connection error:

[image: Epson Scan2 Connection Error]

Which is not very telling.

**Edit:** this happens in any scanner software I have tried: *Epson Scan 2* or *Simple Scan* of *gscan2pdf*.

I am managing the printer/scanner with cups (*http://localhost:631/printers/?*) and I think I am using the latest driver software:

`EPSON_XP-2100_Series   [...] - epson-inkjet-printer-escpr 1.7.26-1lsb3.2 (Seiko Epson Corporation LSB 3.2) Idle`

Finally I have tried to restart the network (router, PC, printer - in this order, like it is recommended in the manual. I have also renewed the WiFi connection of the printer.

Now I am out of ideas, did anyone see this before?

Comment: which scanner app are you using? [edit] in to your question

Comment: @graham done, it is EpsonScan2 or simple-scan or gscan2pdf.